Play with Google map - React JS / Next JS
I'm working on ReactJS App, I have created func. to check agent on map as vector images on particular county.
On first time map load, As per user selection I'm showing marker for that location and on-click of particular marker I want to show county as vector format on map along with marker.
received below error.
Attempted to load a Vector Map, but failed. Falling back to Raster. Please see
I want to understand why I'm getting this error.
I want to show Marker & Vector on county both on Google map using reactjs.
